# Render recharts chart in RTL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

When I'm using recharts to render a chart in in a wrapper which is RTL (for Arabic or Hebrew), the UI gets messed up. Does the library provide an API for RTL rendering?

```
<div className="right-to-left">
     <PieChart width={400} height={250} onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}>
         <Tooltip/>
         <Legend />
         <Pie data={data}></Pie>
     </PieChart>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by RTL container? Can you please add some code and a screenshot to show what's messed up?

Comment: By that I mean that the wrapping html element is f direction right to left. The axes and the legend appears wrong. There must be an API for using rechars right to left

Comment: Not sure what's messed in your code or css. But maybe you can re-create it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-emhgtg).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is meant by UI messed up. We had a problem that the Tooltip position was not calculated properly and it was not at the cursor.

I have found solution to this here:

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/263

Apparently, the element with class `.recharts-wrapper` should have the property `direction: ltr`. Additionally, I reversed the direction and orientation of axes  (`reversed` for XAxis and `orientation` for YAxis) via props.

This solution works for me in RTL environment:

```js
<ResponsiveContainer>
    <LineChart data={sortedData} style={{direction: 'ltr'}}>
        <XAxis
            dataKey="date"
            reversed={true} 
        />
        <YAxis
            dataKey="score"
            orientation="right"
            scale="linear"
        />
        <Tooltip
            content={<CustomTooltip />}
        />
        <Line dataKey="score" type="monotone" />
    </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```